# How to set a maximum per page in laravel dynamically?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a Products class that looks for these paginated items, but in the front end I allow the user to define how many items he wants to display per page (10, 30, 50, 100) the problem is that if someone passes 1000, the api returns 1000 records per page.

How can I validate this for all controllers and models dynamically?

I could do this "easily" by validating each request ('limit') on each controller, but it would not be practical, how can I do that?

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $perPage = $request->input('limit'); // User input 
    $sort = 'global_performance';
    $descending = 'desc';
    $products = Product::where('status', 1)
       ->orderBy($sort, $descending)
       ->paginate($perPage); // 

    return $products;
}
```

Comment: do you have exisiting code are you now starting to write your code?

Comment: I do not have any code because I do not know where to put it to get dynamic on all controllers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily create a middleware. Apply it simply from kernel to each and every route or make a group in your route file to apply it to selective routes.

Inside the middleware just check the limit, if empty or more than the max limit you want let's say 100, make it 100 like so:

```
$limit = $request->input('limit');
if (empty($limit) || ($limit > 100)) {
   $request['limit'] = 100;
}
```

wouldn't that work?

Here is [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware) for middlewares in Laravel.

Comment: Maybe the middleware is what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: no problem, I have updated the answer with the middleware link in Laravel. Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped resolve your issue so that we may close this thread on StackOverflow. thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can validate the limit like this:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
          'limit' => ['required', 'integer', Rule::in([10, 30, 50, 100])]
    ]);
    $perPage = $request->input('limit'); // User input 
    $sort = 'global_performance';
    $descending = 'desc';
    $products = Product::where('status', 1)
       ->orderBy($sort, $descending)
       ->paginate($perPage); // 

    return $products;
}
```

Now, add following line in just before controller class:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
```

**Update**

More dynamic way might be creating custom request class like this:

Run following command to create a new form request class:

```
php artisan make:request PaginateRequest
```

This will create `PaginateRequest` class at `App\Http\Requests` directory like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class PaginateRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

Now change this class into following:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class PaginateRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'limit' => ['required', 'integer', Rule::in([10, 30, 50, 100])]
        ];
    }
}
```

After this, you can use in controller function by adding it as function parameter.

```
public function index(PaginateRequest $request)
{
    $perPage = $request->input('limit'); // User input 
    $sort = 'global_performance';
    $descending = 'desc';
    $products = Product::where('status', 1)
       ->orderBy($sort, $descending)
       ->paginate($perPage); // 

    return $products;
}
```

Please don't forget to import it just before controller class like this:

```
use App\Http\Requests\PaginateRequest;
```

In this way, You can use this request class everywhere you need.

You can see more at documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation

Comment: Could you not even go one step further and create this as a Global Scope you attach to the modal so that every query using that model automatically has the rule applied?

Comment: @Petay87 I am not familiar about that still we can put all validation logic in separate request class ;)

Comment: Hello, I did not want to do this in every method, controller, I wanted something more dynamic do you understand? So you do not have to keep calling in every method.

Comment: @viniciussvl  I have updated my answer you can look at this one.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#query-scopes then use the validation on the scope. That way, anytime you call from the model, the validation is automatically applied. If you ever want it without the validation, create a clone of the model without the scope applied.

Comment: @SagarGautam `$this->validate($request,`  on index() will fail because isn't array...